# Add an event for a custom slot of a button in PyQt6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6

I don't know how to pass an event to a custom slot. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is an example of my code.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow): 

    def setUpMainWindow(self):
         btn2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked, somevent)
  
    def buttonClicked(self,someevent):
         check if the button was rightclicked
```

I want to connect the button to a custom slot (function) in the main window , that when it is clicked do something... but only do something if it's a right click!! So basically I want to check if it's a right click. I cannot do this in the button class, as I have to draw a line if the button is right clicked, so it would really help if the buttonclicked function is in the main class(which has my canvas) instead of a mousepressevent in the button class. Again I greatly appreciate any ideas or help!

Comment: The common solution is to subclass QPushButton, add a custom signal and override its mouse event handlers (`mousePressEvent()` and/or `mouseReleaseEvent()`) then emit the signal from there.

Comment: `if QApplication.instance().mouseButtons() & Qt.RightButton: ...`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Maybe I misunderstood the request, but it seems that the OP is asking about triggering `buttonClicked` only for right button clicks, and since that function was connected to `clicked` (which is only emitted when the left mouse button is released within the button geometry), that's not enough.

Comment: @musicamante The state of the buttons can still be checked in a `clicked` signal handler. Thus if the right button is held down whilst the left button is clicked, the current state can be used to decide what to do. Personally, I find this more natural than a right-click by itself, because it provides visual activation of the button (similar to a Ctrl+click). I suppose you could just connect to the button's context-menu signal instead, but that's not a true click. Anyway, this did at least prompt me to find a better duplicate, so if you have an alternative solution, please post an answer there.

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity, I meant a right click only, because in my application a left click is used to drag and drop. So I thought a right click to draw lines between buttons would be more intuituve! And thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @Sarahjane The common convention is that most immediate actions are performed from the "main" click button (the left one), while the right button is used for context menus. Maybe you can consider a different approach, which involves keyboard modifiers: if no modifier is pressed, proceed with your drag and drop, if Ctrl and/or Shift are pressed, use the alternate action (avoid using Alt as modifier if you plan to use Linux, as it's commonly used for moving windows).

Comment: Okayy @musicamante , Thank you so much for your help! I will discuss it with my collegues, and your plan worked , by using a custom slot I was able to do it! Thank you!